# Google scripts for loop, emailing from a list if a cell is 0

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Column B is the value I'm testing and Column C is the email I want to send an email to if the value of Column B is 0. The function runs but it does not email

```
function email() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('email');
  var range = ss.getRange('B1:B29');
  var email = ss.getRange('C1:C29');
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++){
    var recipient = email[i]
    var x = range[i]
    if(x == 0){
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,
                    "Fill in Schedule for next Week",
                    "Your Schedule for next week isn't filled out. Please fill this in by Sunday\n https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yo8neePMv5rB-JRvgFOL6SKo83jv-FBoNuldcSynsUY/edit#gid=0 \n(Automated Message)",
                    {noReply:true});
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Well, `range` is an object of class `Range`, which per your code spans multiple rows in the column J. Perhaps you meant to iterate the data in that range? I recommend you import the data you want from your sheet into a single JavaScript `Array`, and then iterate that 2D array. The wrong way to do your loop would be to call `getValue()` once for every row you need to process. I recommend you review the API reference, paying particular attention to the `Sheet` and `Range` classes: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

Comment: I don't see what your question or problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just needed to use the .getValues() to convert the variables into proper arrays

```
var range = ss.getRange('B1:B29').getValues();
var email = ss.getRange('C1:C29').getValues();
```